# Can I reference an instance method when I declare a block in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have an instance method that I'd like to invoke directly using the callback param from a block in objective-c. I prefer this approach when I need to do more than a simple 1 liner in the callback.

Here is the basic setup...

I init a class w/ some type of call back so I can parse json after the http request lets say

```
- (void)initFooAndDoStuff {
    Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithCallback:^(NSData * response){
        // do stuff
    }];
}

//this is the instance method I'd like to invoke instead of an inline function
- (void)callBackWithHttpResponse:(NSData *)response {
    // do stuff ... assuming it's more complex than a 1 liner that is
}
```

I can setup a call back that does something inline (but again more complex stuff would be better in a stand alone instance method perhaps)

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithCallback:^(NSData * response){ 
    NSLog(@"foo"); 
}];
```

I can use the instance method like below but it feels a little long winded. Any way I can cut this down (the syntax that is).

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithCallback:^(NSData * response){ 
    [self callBackWithHttpResponse:response]; 
}];
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to declare one block and copy or reuse it again and again instead of having to re-declare it inline each time?

Comment: Blocks are generally *less* cumbersome than the old target-and-selector technique that predated them. Your last code snippet is pretty concise and simple, I think. If you want to do the target-and-selector approach, then design `Foo` to work that way.

Comment: @Ken can u show and example of this? Evan would the delegate syntax reduce the noise I'm talking about?

Comment: `Foo` might define `- (id) initWithTarget:(id)target callbackSelector:(SEL)selector`. It would save the `target` and the `selector` in ivars. It would be called like `[[Foo alloc] initWithTarget:self callbackSelector:@selector(callBackWithHttpResponse:)]`. To call the callback, `Foo` would do `[_target performSelector:_selector withObject:response]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to put the implementation in a method, you might as well just have the method return the entire block:

```
-(void (^)(NSData *))httpResponseHandler {
    return ^(NSData *responseData){
        // do something with responseData
    };
}
```

Then the places you use it would be a bit more succinct:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithCallback:[self httpResponseHandler]];
```

Comment: awesome! this is exactly what I was looking for! (funny I ended up on your blog this morning after some issue with ocmock. Keep up the great objective-c / iOS mentoring **we need more developers like yourself in the community)

Comment: I'm not really sure how that is a simplification -- more of a lateral move in terms of complexity -- but it certainly is a perfectly valid (and useful -- I do similar things all the time) pattern. Upvote!

Comment: @bbum I agree, not a simplification per se, depends a lot on how you might re-use the implementation--the callback method embedded in inline block is probably more flexible overall. But I do like to [return blocks from methods as a design practice](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/05/block-initialization-for-testability-and-reuse) where it's relevant.

Comment: I dont know if its valid/accepted way to use this pattern, but i use it to free up delegate methods for cleaner code. Example: If there is much communication between VCa and VCb, i send a dictionary from VCa to VCb containing all the methods VCb needs to call on VCa. So instead of cluttering up the VC-chain with delegate call backs, VCb can just call the methods stored in the dictionary. This keeps "encapsulation" i think? and it reduces multiple delegate methods to only one. Maybe you guys can comment if this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithCallback:^(NSData * response){ 
    [self callBackWithHttpResponse:response]; 
}];
```

OK -- pretty darned readable as it is.

Now, go in the other room and hit yourself in the head 3 times with a brick to simulate not having looked at this project in 6 months to a year.

Now, read the code again.

Still readable, isn't it?

There is nothing wrong with a bit of verbosity when that verbosity says exactly what the code is doing.  You could go with a target/action pattern as Ken Thomases suggested, but that would require additional complexity elsewhere.

Instead of `callback`, I would change it to be even more specific.  I.e. if the callback was really a completion handler:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] initWithHTTPResponseCompletionHandler:^(NSData * response){ 
    [self httpResponseCompletionHandler:response]; 
}];
```

Comment: I'll agree -the complexity on the other end appears to be > what I'm already doing when I alloc/init the web service class. I was simply curious to see what other options I had as I'm fairly new to objective-c block syntax (thanks for the replies)